# google cloud speech SpeechClient not found

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, speech-recognition, google-speech-api

I use intellij idea, i have included the google cloud speech api but he dont finde the SpeechClient (https://image.prntscr.com/image/3S9bjQWgRdGGB1olHihxkA.png) (https://image.prntscr.com/image/RVspqW2-QuqD2mytN3V8Qw.png) why? I dont now why the java code not found this data in google documenten is this code working its the example code.
https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-usage-java

https://image.prntscr.com/image/fFVm7P7SRheGYWCqTvdDAQ.png

```
package de.****.test;

import com.google.cloud.speech.v1.RecognitionAudio;
import com.google.cloud.speech.v1.RecognitionConfig;
import com.google.cloud.speech.v1.RecognitionConfig.AudioEncoding;
import com.google.cloud.speech.v1.RecognizeResponse;
import com.google.cloud.speech.v1.SpeechClient;
import com.google.cloud.speech.v1.SpeechRecognitionAlternative;
import com.google.cloud.speech.v1.SpeechRecognitionResult;
import com.google.protobuf.ByteString;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.List;

public class main {

    /**
     * Demonstrates using the Speech API to transcribe an audio file.
     */
    public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
        // Instantiates a client
        try (SpeechClient speechClient = SpeechClient.create()) {

            // The path to the audio file to transcribe
            String fileName = "./resources/audio.raw";

            // Reads the audio file into memory
            Path path = Paths.get(fileName);
            byte[] data = Files.readAllBytes(path);
            ByteString audioBytes = ByteString.copyFrom(data);

            // Builds the sync recognize request
            RecognitionConfig config = RecognitionConfig.newBuilder()
                    .setEncoding(AudioEncoding.LINEAR16)
                    .setSampleRateHertz(16000)
                    .setLanguageCode("en-US")
                    .build();
            RecognitionAudio audio = RecognitionAudio.newBuilder()
                    .setContent(audioBytes)
                    .build();

            // Performs speech recognition on the audio file
            RecognizeResponse response = speechClient.recognize(config, audio);
            List<SpeechRecognitionResult> results = response.getResultsList();

            for (SpeechRecognitionResult result : results) {
                // There can be several alternative transcripts for a given chunk of speech. Just use the
                // first (most likely) one here.
                SpeechRecognitionAlternative alternative = result.getAlternativesList().get(0);
                System.out.printf("Transcription: %s%n", alternative.getTranscript());
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Did you find any solution?